# SIGSEGV in Mono 2.6.7 running Denian Lenny

Tags: linux, exception, mono, debian, segmentation-fault

I recently installed mono 2.6.7 on my debian lenny and I am trying to run a minecraft server. Everything I run the mono command i get the error from below:

```
Stacktrace
Native stacktrace
         mono [0x536e71]
         mono [0x43f5ed]
        /lib/libpthread.so.0 [0x2ba796fa4a80]
         mono [0x43f571]
        /lib/libpthread.so.0 [0x2ba796fa4a80]
        [0x40136834]
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries used by your application.
=================================================================
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any idea on what would fix this?

Comment: Is that a backported version of Mono? I say this cuz that version of Mono is not available in Lenny, but is in Squeeze.

Comment: he's probably built this from source, (i have). I wouldn't really tag this exception-handling. You can't "handle" a segfault.